# How to Display Two Query Side by Side using SQL

Tags: sql, outer-join, full-outer-join

I have the following 2 queries that are almost identical except the second query contains a table join, where clause and has less FAXDEPTs(the commented out portion is included in Query 2 just shared the one query to make easier to read).

I want to join the two queries by FAXDEPT and have the results look something like this,

FAXDEPT| TOTAL DOCUMENTS(Query1)|TOTAL PAGES (Query1)|TOTAL DOCUMENTS(Query2)|TOTAL PAGES (Query2)

Query 1 contains more FAXDEPTs than Query2. Is there a way I can display "0"s for Query 2 TOTAL PAGES and TOTAL DOCS
I'm assumed I would do some sort of FUll OUTER JOIN but can't seem to get it to work. Not sure if using alias is part of my issue or not. I appreciate all the help in advance!

```
 select sq.faxdept 'Fax Department', count(sq.docid)'Total Documents', sum(sq.pages)'Total Pages' 
from
    (
    select idp.id as docid, (MAX(idp.pagenum)+1) as pages, ki178.keyvaluechar as faxdept
    from DOCDATA dd
    left join FAXDEPT ki178 on id.id = ki178.id
    left join IMPORTSOURCE ki228 on id.id = ki228.id
    left join BATCHINFO kgd105 on dd.id = kgd105.id
    left join PAGEDATA idp on id.id = idp.id
    --left join QUEUE ilc on id.id = ilc.id
    where
    id.datestored > '10/07/2021' and id.status = 0  
    --and ilc.num = 252
    and (kgd105.kg128 like 'DISC DIP%SJIN%' or  ki228.keyvaluechar like 'SJIN' )
    group by idp.id, ki178.keyvaluechar
    ) 
as sq
group by sq.faxdept
```

Comment: Are you aware of union's? That seems less complicated than this, but potentially less efficient... Just wanted to know if you couldn't use a union or if there was a reason you were avoiding them

Comment: I thought UNION would merge the two queries to sit on top of each other and only have 3 columns?

Comment: Its important that the queries display side by side as they are resulting on two different areas